# iterative string substitution

Tags: string, r, gsub

I have a string and I want to add swap in a substring every 3 characters and generate 1 output for each iteration: for example

```
print(str1)
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD

print(str2)
nnn
```

the output should look like this

```
nnnDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
DDDnnnDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
DDDDDDnnnDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
DDDDDDDDDnnnDDDDDDDDDDDDD
DDDDDDDDDDDDnnnDDDDDDDDDD
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDnnnDDDDDD
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDnnnDDD
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDnnn
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
positions <-  seq(1, nchar(str1), by=nchar(str2))
split.str1 <- substring(str1, positions, positions+nchar(str2)-1)

result <- sapply(seq(nchar(str1)/nchar(str2))
                 , function(i) {
                   split.str1[i] <- str2
                   paste(split.str1, collapse='')
                 })
result
## [1] "nnnDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD" "DDDnnnDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD" "DDDDDDnnnDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD" "DDDDDDDDDnnnDDDDDDDDDDDD"
## [5] "DDDDDDDDDDDDnnnDDDDDDDDD" "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDnnnDDDDDD" "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDnnnDDD" "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDnnn"
```

Thanks @BondedDust for the matrix suggestion for presentation:

```
as.matrix(result)
##      [,1]                      
## [1,] "nnnDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD"
## [2,] "DDDnnnDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD"
## [3,] "DDDDDDnnnDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD"
## [4,] "DDDDDDDDDnnnDDDDDDDDDDDD"
## [5,] "DDDDDDDDDDDDnnnDDDDDDDDD"
## [6,] "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDnnnDDDDDD"
## [7,] "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDnnnDDD"
## [8,] "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDnnn"
```

Comment: It would look more like what was requested if you wrapped `as.matrix` around it.